# how to combine pdf files into one from a tempfile in Python

Tags: python, pdf, temporary-files

I have a python code that creates a temporary pdf files from tableau views and sends it to the slack channel separately.
I want to combine them together into one file but I can't figure out how to do it.
I am fairly new to python and would really appreciate some help in how to use PdfFileMerger in the code below.
i've tried to use

> merger.append(f)

after f variable but it doesn't  work giving me ar error **                AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'seek'
** what should I put in brackets?

```
        for view_item in all_views :
            with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.pdf', delete=True) as temp_file:

                #server.views.populate_image(view_item, req_options=image_req_option)
                server.views.populate_pdf(view_item, req_options = pdf_req_option)

                print('got the image')

                temp_file.write(view_item.pdf)

                temp_file.file.seek(0) 
                print('in the beginnign again')

                f = {'file': (temp_file.name,temp_file, 'pdf')}
                merger.append(f)

                response = requests.post(url='https://slack.com/api/files.upload', data=
                           {'token': bot_token, 'channels': slack_channels[0], 'media': f,'title': '{} {}'.format(view_item.name, yesterday), 'initial_comment' :''},
                           headers={'Accept': 'application/json'}, files=f)
                print('the image is in the channel')
```

Comment: You'll probably need pyPdf2's PdfFileMerger...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to feed PdfFileMerger the file objects, like so, not a dict.

Since PdfFileMerger will do things in-memory anyway, there's no need to write to tempfiles on the disk, a BytesIO in memory will do fine.

```
import io

merger = PdfFileMerger()
for view_item in all_views:
    server.views.populate_pdf(view_item, req_options=pdf_req_option)
    # Write retrieved data into memory file
    tf = io.BytesIO()
    tf.write(view_item.pdf)
    tf.seek(0)
    # Add it to the merger
    merger.append(tf)

# Write merged data into memory file
temp_file = io.BytesIO()
merger.write(temp_file)
temp_file.seek(0)

f = {'file': ('merged.pdf', temp_file, 'pdf')}
# Slack stuff here...
```

Comment: Thank u so very much for the help! )